# Doxygen documentation for python ".tp_doc" attribute…

Tags: python, c, doxygen

I have a Class-Library with all the **doxygen** documentation located in the c-header file… now I have a **python** api wrapper using **python** *types* and *methods* related to c-api *types* and *functions*…

Question… HOW I get the **\brief** and **\details** documentation out of the c-heder file into the **python** `.tpdoc`… attribute ??

a real good help would be that **doxygen** produce an `index` file with c-function-name → **\brief** and **\detail** information… ?perhaps more?

I would read *THIS* `index` file and add the info to the **python** api.

→ Thanks For Help

example:

```
/// \brief create a \e master/slave link between the master-parent-context and the slave-parent-context …
///
/// \param[in] ctx the \e master context object as PARENT without a CHILD
/// \slaveid
/// \param[in] slave the \e slave context object as CLIENT-PARENT without a CHILD
/// \retMqErrorE
/// \attention The \e slave-context is owned by the \e master-context.
/// This mean that no other external references should be used and the \e slave-context
/// will be deleted if the \e master-context is be deleted.
MQ_EXTERN enum MqErrorE
MQ_DECL MqSlaveCreate (
  struct MqS * const  ctx,
  MQ_SLAVE_ID const   id,
  struct MqS * const  slave
);
```

**python** api…

```
static PyMethodDef MqC_Methods[] = {
...
    { "SlaveCreate", NS(MqC_SlaveCreate), METH_VARARGS, "\brief doc…" },
...
}
```

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Please show some code to make your question a bit clear.

Comment: doxygen: 1.8.11

Comment: 1.8.11 is already a couple of years old, what happens with the 1.8.14 version? Problem for me is taht the example is still to incomplete. Maybe you have to look at the commands line `\copybrief` etc.

Comment: the problem is not to setup a new **doxygen** documentation… the problem is to get the **\brief** documentation from the *source-c-api-function* into the "doc" label of the *python-c-api-method*… all on **C**-level

Comment: OK now I do get what you want. This is transfer data from C comment to C code or the other way around. I think this can only be accomplished with some preprocessing (maybe even the need of some code generator.  I don't have an off the shelf solution for this. I tried something with `\snippetdoc` and including the string into cpp code (`"\n //[snip1] \ntext \n //[snip1] "\n`     where \n are the regular comment signs in the code but not allowed in comments here) but got an error message on a non closed `"` when compiling.